# Best method copying folders in C++ on Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a simple program to copy all files in folders from one drive to another using C++.  Using the Windows API function `CopyFile()`. I have used the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "File Copier Version 1";

    CopyFile("U:\\whateverfile.file","U:\\whateverfile2.file",0);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to handle copying an entire directory and all the files in it?  Any other advice on this?  Problems I may encounter?

Comment: Create the new directory. Iterate through the files in the source directory using FindFirstFile/FindNextFile, copy each file as it's found.

Comment: The documentation for FindFirstFile has a [link to an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of listing the files in a directory. You can modify it to copy instead of printing each file. To move the directory instead, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to do it on Windows with progress display and other features, without putting too much effort into it, look up `IFileOperation::CopyItem`. However, it requires Vista or later.

Comment: +1.  For pre-Vista, there's also SHFileOperation.  The advantage to using either of these over doing your own loop with FileFirstFile/FindNextFile is that it will save you from lots of details like proper Unicode support, junction points, etc.  They can even provide UI and cancel buttons if you choose.